# Static class best practice

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static

I have a project where CurrentSettings and CurrentUser classes are needed in every controller.
I was using static classes to get these, but someone suggested Wrapper classes because using static classes is bad.

My issue is that in every controller I have to do this:

```
    #region Fields

    private readonly ProfileService service;
    private readonly Profile currentUser;
    private readonly Settings currentSettings;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public _UsersController()
    {
        var companyWrapper = new CompanyWrapper();
        var profileWrapper = new ProfileWrapper();
        var settingsWrapper = new SettingsWrapper();

        var companyId = companyWrapper.CurrentCompanyId();

        service = new ProfileService(companyId);
        currentUser = profileWrapper.CurrentUser();
        currentSettings = settingsWrapper.CurrentSiteSettings();
    }

    #endregion
```

which I think is a nightmare. Surely there is a better cleaner way of doing this.
If anyone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

PS: I use the repository/service design pattern for almost everything within this project.

Cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this question

Comment: Using static classes is not bad.

Comment: I'd be more worried about the [regions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/the-problem-with-code-folding.html)!

Comment: use static or Session variable, ll' be best approach, i do use session variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must understand why you are making changes. Don't just make changes just because someone says it is better. It's all about context. What are you trying to achieve with this change?

One important reason for hiding static classes behind a wrapper is to allow your code to be more testable. When you want to be able to test classes, static methods are often (but not always) in the way. In this case letting your controllers depend on a static class that provides you with user context information will certainly be in the way of unit testing your controllers, since the information this class provides will be based on things like the `HttpContext` or the session. The HTTP context is not available in your unit test suite and you should prevent depending on this, since this makes your unit tests fragile and hard to maintain.

So instead of letting your controllers depend on that static class, you can let them depend on an interface, for instance `IUserContext`. In your web application, you can have an implementation that forwards the calls to the static class, but in your unit tests you should use a fake implementation of that interface. This prevents the unit tests from using ASP.NET specific classes and allows you to supply a controller with a fake user for testing purposes.

And still, even if you're not unit testing your code (what you probably should be doing anyway) depending on abstractions can make your application more flexible and maintainable, but you'll have to decide this on a case-by-case base.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using inheritance to allow you to reuse the functionality without repeating the same code?

You could, for example, create a base class that in the default constructor instantiated the required classes.  That way, you would be able to access them from the child classes without repeating the code.

```
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
```

Comment: that's fine when its about reducing redundant code, but here he want to retain data

Comment: The idea to create a wrapper class (that implements a certain interface) is that you can test your controller more easily. That won't be the case when you just move that logic to a base class. That would make everything much harder to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Controller that has those fields.